# If I stored the blockchain in shared storage, can multiple miners work on it?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, leveldb

So I have a crazy idea to speed up the mining process.   If I stored the blockchain in /data/ethData (which is on shared storage like a SAN), I can then mount it on multiple machines and then have miner workers go at it.    Do you think it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, LevelDB is designed to be single threaded.